Calling Child component method from Parent component
I want to call a method in my Child component when an event is fired in my Parent component, I have done research and this seems the consensus way of doing it in script setup:
// Parent Component
<template>
     <tr @click="gameStats" title="Click for Game Stats">
      // Markup
      <nflGameStats
            ref="childGetStats"
        />
</template>

<script setup>
import nflGameStats from "./nfl-game-stats.vue";

const childGetStats = ref(null);
function gameStats() {
    console.log("In gameStats.");
    childGetStats.value.getStats();
}
</script>

Child Component (nfl-game-stats.vue):
<script setup>
import { defineExpose } from "vue";

const getStats = () => {
    // Do stuff
};

defineExpose({ getStats });

</script>

Console logs error - "Uncaught TypeError: childGetStats.value.getStats is not a function"
I have gone over several articles all say this should work. Any help much appreciated.

There is nothing wrong with the code. Problem probably lies in some other code not shown. Provide runnable demo if you can. However, best practice is for parent components to not directly call child component methods, which is why components are closed by default, requiring explicit opt-in using defineExpose.  If at all possible, find some other way to do this.  Possibly rethink whether the click element can be moved to the child, or getStats function moved to the parent. Another possibility is to communicate between components with props and/or emits, or use global state.

Yes thanks for reply. I realized later that
 <nflGameStats ref="childGetStats" />

was wrapped in a v-for so I had an array of the functions and had to call the function with the proper array index
<tr @click=" childGetStats[totalCount].getStats(
    gameInfo.game.id)"                                           title="Click for Game Stats">

